# Argparse debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, argparse

To simplify, here is code that fails in debug. There are two problems:

1. I cannot seem to create a run configuration that allows for passing arguments in either debug or non-debug mode.
2. This code always fails in debug mode?

   ```
   import argparse
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument('filename', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
   args = parser.parse_args()
   print("Filename: ", args.filename)
   ```

Here is a sample configuration for Run:

```
        {
            "name": "Python: filetest.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": 
            "${workspaceFolder}/filetest.py",
            "args": [
                "./samples/blja2.wav"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
```

Comment: What does `argparse` have to do with whatever debug mode you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse


def argparse_sample():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('sample_args', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print("File Content: ", args.sample_args.readlines())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    argparse_sample()
```

So without the debug mode:
Output:

```
$ python main.py sample_args.txt
Filename:  ['        {\n', '            "name": "Python: filetest.py",\n', '            "type": "python",\n', '
   "request": "launch",\n', '            "program": \n', '            "${workspaceFolder}/filetest.py",\n', '
 "args": [\n', '                "./samples/blja2.wav"\n', '            ],\n', '            "console": "integratedTermina
l"\n', '        }']
```

With debug mode in PyCharm:
[PyCharm debug settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9gt1.png)

Output:

```
C:\projects\StackOverFlow\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/projects/StackOverFlow/main.py sample_args.txt
Filename:  ['        {\n', '            "name": "Python: filetest.py",\n', '            "type": "python",\n', '            "request": "launch",\n', '            "program": \n', '            "${workspaceFolder}/filetest.py",\n', '            "args": [\n', '                "./samples/blja2.wav"\n', '            ],\n', '            "console": "integratedTerminal"\n', '        }']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Visual Studio Code Debugger settings (launch.json):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {   "args": ["sample_args.txt"],
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\projects\StackOverFlow>  c:; cd 'c:\projects\StackOverFlow'; & 'C:\Python38\python.exe' 'c:\Users\alist\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1159798656\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '49710' '--' 'c:\projects\StackOverFlow\main.py' 'sample_args.txt'
Filename:  ['        {\n', '            "name": "Python: filetest.py",\n', '            "type": "python",\n', '            "request": "launch",\n', '            "program": \n', '            "${workspaceFolder}/filetest.py",\n', '            "args": [\n', '                "./samples/blja2.wav"\n', '            ],\n', '            "console": "integratedTerminal"\n', '        }']
```

Comment: I get an exception for the debug case (and the non-debug fails to find the arguments). The exception is: Exception has occurred: SystemExit
2
  File "/home/joem5636/Documents/GitHub/WireFFT/filetest.py", line 5, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()

Comment: In order to pass arguments in Visual Studio Code debugging mode, you need to add your arguments to launch.json (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging). Do you have a launch.json file? If yes, are you passing your argument the way I am passing above?